# How do I create a Swift variable where under certain conditions it can return a different value, but normally it just returns itself?

Tags: swift

Say I have a variable called `favoriteFood` and it's a `String`. It's on a view controller for instance.

I want it to be a normal variable you can get and set. But under a very specific circumstance I want to be able to return a custom value, so for instance:

```swift
var favoriteFood: String {
    if isTuesday {
        return "carrots"
    } else {
        return favoriteFood
    }
}
```

But this triggers a ton of errors and warnings and doesn't let me set it anymore.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Could you tell us more about your use case? A simple computed property may be appropriate, but depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve, using polymorphism might be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a private backing property, and a create custom getter and setter for `favoriteFood`. The setter should set the value to the backing property, while the getter either returns `"carrots"` if the condition is met or the value of the backing property otherwise.

```
private var _favoriteFood: String = ""

var favoriteFood: String {
    get {
        if isTuesday {
            return "carrots"
        } else {
            return _favoriteFood
        }
    }

    set {
        _favoriteFood = newValue
    }
}
```